# Does the opposite of nested cross-validation make sense?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, sparse

I'm asking the question from a machine learning point of view. I have a dataset with relatively high sparsity, so if I use nested cross-validation for my feature tuning and evaluation, that is tune using CV and test on a separate test set after, I get quite different results if I re-sample the datasets (keeping the proportions) and repeat the tuning process. I wouldn't be bothered by some difference, but in my case the differences cannot be ignored.

I want to try the opposite configuration in which I train on X, and test on Y during development, and then evaluate final results using CV on X+Z where Z is of the same size as Y. Or even simply have X to train during development and Y to test, and then CV on X for final evaluation. Is this cheating? Has someone done this before (references would be useful)? Does it make sense?

Comment: Interesting question. Could you elaborate on the second paragraph and explain the scheme of actions in more detail? For example, what does Z stand for?

Comment: In the second paragraph I refer to two splits, X-Y and X-Y-Z, both summing to the whole data. In the case where there is a Z, I thought it might make sense to have the same training and testing proportions during the development and the evaluation (dev: traininging on X testing on Y; final evaluation: CV on X+Z, training on X-sized sample from X+Z and testing on the rest, which is the size of Y). That is not always necessary though, so I guess it should work with an X-Y split --- dev: training on X, testing on Y; final eval: CV on X. I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

> two splits, X-Y and X-Y-Z, both summing to the whole data. In the case where there is a Z, I thought it might make sense to have the same training and testing proportions during the development and the evaluation (dev: traininging on X testing on Y; final evaluation: CV on X+Z, training on X-sized sample from X+Z and testing on the rest, which is the size of Y)

While training on X also for the evaluation with Z is obviously closer to the settings during X-Y development, the advantage of using X+Y for training the final model (which is tested by Z) is that X+Y are more cases, thus maybe a slightly better model can be built. You could also see this as a (weak?) counter measure to the risk of overfitting during the X-Y development process.

> have X to train during development and Y to test, and then CV on X for final evaluation

This one is cheating: during the cross validation you'd test on cases that have actually entered the model (somewhat indirectly, but still: those cases were used for development)

> I get quite different results if I re-sample the datasets (keeping the proportions) and repeat the tuning process.

This means your models are *unstable*. You should either restrict the complexity or maybe use variance reduction techniques like *bagging* / *ensemble models*.

Comment: If we assume that the second one is cheating, then shouldn't we assume the same, though slightly less so, for the first? I mean, the first one uses slightly more data and a small part of it is completely "clean", but if the rest is "dirty" then?...

Comment: Alexandar, you can use the dirty data (X + Y) for *fitting* the model without problem. Just the test data Z needs to be clean. which is the case if I undestood you correctly. (It is true though that there are some aspects of statistical independence that random resampling or splitting schemes cannot achieve - but those call for a properly designed validation study. E.g. if you need to show that your prediction is still good for data acquired months or years after the model was built)